# google tag manager click text not working in Google chrome

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

On my website header there is a tab that when clicked will send the user to the required page in the website.

THe header tabs are like below

- House
- House Loan
- Rent

I have created an event tag and a corresponding trigger that work correctly.

I have also created a Lookup variable to display user friendly data in my reports

Lookup Variable (Home Information):

```
House Loan > Loan for you dream home
House Rent > Rent your house
```

My event tag configuration:

```
Category: House
Action: Inquiry
Label : {{Home Information}}
```

When a user clicks the tab, the tag is fired and data is sent correctly in Fire Fox but in Google Chrome the event label is not getting captured. It is showing **"not set "**.

I am trying to capture this using "**Click Text**" functionality in GTM

```
  <a href="/categories/House-rent" title="House rent" class="house"> 
    "House "
      <br>
     " rent"
     </a>
```

Please let me know what changes need to be done
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: You really need to explain it better, I can't even attempt to edit your question :( I don't really understand you mate.

Comment: Can you please post the configuration of your {{Home Information}} variable? Also, can you share your link?

Comment: Added the image. I cannot share the link as website is internal to organization

Answer (score 0):

In your example there is a double space:

"House " 
< /br >
" rent"

Resulting in "House**rent" not "House*rent".

Comment: I tried with double space to. It is not working in chrome. But working correctly with firefox.